# How to optimize an image processing algorithm with 3 for loops with numpy, C, numba (or CUDA) in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

I wrote the following task where I select in an image only the pixels with color (non black and white) and assign them a value according to a given scale. The current code which has 3 nested for loops takes 61 seconds to run on my MacBook Pro 2015 2.8Ghz Quad-Core Intel Core i7. My question is how can I optimize the code to make it complete faster:

- 1.1 shall I vectorize in numpy?
- 1.2 shall I write an external function in C?
- 1.3 shall I use numba?
- 1.4 I currently don't have a GPU but I want to buy one. Would such a problem be run quicker using a GPU with CUDA code and if yes, what would be the approximate speedup factor with respect to one of the other solutions (1.1, 1.2 or 1.3)?

Many thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import pdb
import time

list_scale_values = [[255, 255, 1], [255, 252, 0], [254, 251, 0], [253, 248, 0], [253, 245, 0], [253, 242, 0], [252, 241, 1], [251, 238, 1], [252, 234, 0], [251, 233, 1], [249, 231, 1], [248, 230, 0], [248, 227, 0], [248, 222, 1], [246, 217, 3], [243, 212, 0], [238, 206, 1], [236, 200, 0], [233, 194, 1], [230, 189, 1], [228, 184, 1], [226, 176, 1], [223, 170, 2], [219, 166, 2], [221, 159, 0], [218, 153, 0], [215, 147, 0], [213, 142, 0], [211, 135, 0], [208, 129, 0], [207, 123, 1], [203, 118, 1], [202, 112, 2], [197, 106, 1], [196, 100, 0], [193, 94, 0], [191, 87, 0], [188, 81, 0], [186, 76, 1], [183, 70, 0], [180, 65, 0], [178, 60, 0], [177, 53, 0], [173, 47, 0], [170, 41, 0], [168, 35, 0], [165, 30, 0], [163, 25, 0], [160, 17, 0], [158, 12, 0], [157, 10, 0], [153, 9, 0], [151, 8, 0], [148, 10, 0], [141, 8, 0], [140, 8, 3], [137, 8, 2], [132, 7, 1], [129, 7, 2], [126, 7, 3], [124, 6, 4], [121, 5, 5], [118, 6, 5], [115, 5, 4], [113, 5, 5], [109, 3, 3], [106, 3, 4], [102, 4, 5], [99, 3, 5], [94, 2, 3], [91, 2, 4], [88, 2, 3], [82, 3, 6], [77, 3, 4], [73, 3, 5], [69, 3, 5], [67, 3, 4], [63, 1, 4], [57, 1, 4], [56, 1, 4], [52, 0, 2], [47, 2, 0], [46, 0, 0], [34, 0, 0], [3, 0, 2], [1, 0, 12], [1, 1, 71], [4, 0, 76], [1, 2, 82], [2, 3, 86], [2, 3, 93], [3, 4, 97], [3, 6, 103], [2, 6, 106], [3, 6, 113], [3, 7, 115], [1, 8, 122], [2, 9, 125], [4, 10, 132], [3, 11, 136], [3, 12, 141], [3, 13, 145], [4, 13, 152], [4, 12, 155], [4, 14, 163], [4, 15, 167], [3, 16, 172], [4, 16, 176], [6, 21, 182], [6, 26, 185], [5, 30, 192], [5, 34, 196], [6, 38, 199], [8, 41, 204], [8, 46, 209], [7, 50, 214], [7, 54, 218], [7, 59, 221], [8, 63, 224], [12, 67, 228], [9, 72, 225], [13, 77, 227], [15, 81, 229], [17, 85, 228], [19, 90, 230], [22, 96, 231], [23, 100, 232], [25, 102, 234], [29, 107, 233], [31, 111, 234], [31, 116, 233], [35, 120, 236], [38, 124, 237], [40, 128, 238], [41, 132, 237], [42, 138, 240], [44, 142, 241], [46, 146, 242], [48, 151, 243], [50, 156, 244], [50, 159, 244], [53, 164, 246], [56, 169, 247], [56, 174, 246], [60, 176, 249], [62, 180, 250], [63, 187, 251], [66, 190, 252], [68, 194, 253], [71, 197, 255], [73, 203, 255], [75, 207, 255], [78, 211, 255], [82, 213, 255], [87, 216, 255], [90, 218, 253], [94, 221, 254], [100, 223, 255], [105, 226, 255], [108, 230, 254], [112, 230, 255], [118, 234, 255], [121, 236, 255], [126, 239, 255], [131, 241, 255], [136, 242, 255], [142, 246, 255], [144, 248, 255]]

aliasing_velocity_cm_s = 46
scale_values_velocity = np.linspace(aliasing_velocity_cm_s, -aliasing_velocity_cm_s, num=len(list_scale_values))

list_scale_values_velocity = np.array(scale_values_velocity[:]).tolist()

# ensure black is zero
list_scale_values_velocity[int(len(list_scale_values_velocity)/2)] = 0

cropped_image = np.random.randint(256, size=(300, 300, 3)) # generate an image with 300x300 pixels of random value with 3 channels of 256 bits

velocity_image = np.zeros((cropped_image.shape[0], cropped_image.shape[1], 1))
start_time = time.time()
for i_frame in range(cropped_image.shape[0]):
    for j_frame in range(cropped_image.shape[1]):
        isColor_score = abs(int(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 0]) - int(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 1])) + abs(
            int(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 0]) - int(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 2]))
        idx_list = 0
        score = 1000
        if isColor_score < 20:
            velocity_image[i_frame, j_frame] = 0
        else:
            for z in range(len(list_scale_values)): 
              score_pixel = abs(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 0] - list_scale_values[z][0]) + abs(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 1] - list_scale_values[z][1]) + abs(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 2] - list_scale_values[z][2]) 
              if score_pixel < score:
                score = score_pixel
                dx_list = z
            velocity_image[i_frame, j_frame] = list_scale_values_velocity[idx_list]  # the velocity is still in cm/s


end = time.time()
elapsed = np.round(end - start_time, 2)
print('Operation finished in {} [s]!'.format(elapsed))
```

Comment: A general rule of thumb: vectorized operations in Python >>> `for` loops. Truly, avoid iteration if you can.

Answer (score 2):

This code can be heavily optimized before needing to use numba or GPU offloading. For-Loops are probably one of the slowest methods to calculate in python, because there is a low of overhead. My suggestions would be:

1.1 use [list comprehensions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) instead of for-loops. They can be magnitudes quicker in python.

1.2 another option would be to not bother with python, and instead use numpy to calculate your operations. For example:

```
color_scores = np.abs(cropped_image[:, :, 0] - cropped_image[:, :, 1]) + np.abs(cropped_image[:, :, 0] - cropped_image[:, :, 2])
```

does what your code does in the loop thousands of times in one operation (and takes a fraction of the time). I measured a 100x speedup for this operation alone.

When it comes to performance in python, rely on numpy functions only. Those are written in C and much, much faster than regular python.

Comment: Thank for your anwer @quantum. I finally used cython and could get a great speed-up

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first I converted the 3 nested for loop in a function as follows `script_plain_pytho.py`:

```
import numpy as np
import pdb

def extract_velocity(cropped_image, velocity_image, arr_scale_values, arr_scale_values_velocity, score):
  #def extract_velocity(cropped_image, velocity_image, list_scale_values, score):
  height = cropped_image.shape[0]
  width = cropped_image.shape[1]
  len_arr_scale_values = len(arr_scale_values)

  for i_frame in range(height):
      for j_frame in range(width):
          isColor_score = np.abs(int(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 0]) - int(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 1])) + np.abs(
              int(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 0]) - int(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 2]))
          idx_list = 0
          if isColor_score < 20:
              velocity_image[i_frame, j_frame] = 0
          else:
              for z in range(len_arr_scale_values): 
                #color_scores = np.abs(cropped_image[:, :, 0] - cropped_image[:, :, 1]) + np.abs(cropped_image[:, :, 0] - cropped_image[:, :, 2])
                score_pixel = np.abs(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 0] - arr_scale_values[z][0]) + np.abs(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 1] - arr_scale_values[z][1]) + np.abs(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 2] - arr_scale_values[z][2]) 
                if score_pixel < score:
                  score = score_pixel
                  dx_list = z
              velocity_image[i_frame, j_frame] = arr_scale_values_velocity[idx_list]  # the velocity is still in cm/s
  return velocity_image
```

I then converted the function into a cython function (saved in `fastloop.pyx`) and learning from this excellent tutorial: https://nealhughes.net/cython1/

```
import numpy as np
import pdb

def extract_velocity(double[:,:,:] cropped_image, double[:,:,:] velocity_image, double[:,:] arr_scale_values, double[:] arr_scale_values_velocity, double score):

  #def extract_velocity(cropped_image, velocity_image, list_scale_values, score):
  #pdb.set_trace()
  cdef int height = cropped_image.shape[0]
  cdef int width = cropped_image.shape[1]
  cdef int len_arr_scale_values = len(arr_scale_values)
  cdef double cropped_image_ij_0
  cdef double cropped_image_ij_1
  cdef double cropped_image_ij_2
  cdef double diff_01
  cdef double diff_02
  cdef double isColor_score
  cdef double arr_scale_values_z_0
  cdef double arr_scale_values_z_1
  cdef double arr_scale_values_z_2
  cdef double diff_03
  cdef double diff_04
  cdef double diff_05
  

  for i_frame in range(height):
      for j_frame in range(width):
          cropped_image_ij_0 = cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 0]
          cropped_image_ij_1 = cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 1]
          cropped_image_ij_2 = cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 2]
          diff_01 = cropped_image_ij_0 - cropped_image_ij_1
          diff_02 = cropped_image_ij_0 - cropped_image_ij_2

          if diff_01 < 0:
            diff_01 = - diff_01
          if diff_02 < 0:
            diff_02 = - diff_02
          isColor_score = diff_01 + diff_02
          #isColor_score = np.abs(int(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 0]) - int(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 1])) + np.abs( int(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 0]) - int(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 2]))
          idx_list = 0
          if isColor_score < 20:
              velocity_image[i_frame, j_frame] = 0
          else:
              for z in range(len_arr_scale_values): 
                #color_scores = np.abs(cropped_image[:, :, 0] - cropped_image[:, :, 1]) + np.abs(cropped_image[:, :, 0] - cropped_image[:, :, 2])
                #score_pixel = np.abs(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 0] - arr_scale_values[z][0]) + np.abs(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 1] - arr_scale_values[z][1]) + np.abs(cropped_image[i_frame, j_frame, 2] - arr_scale_values[z][2]) 
                arr_scale_values_z_0 = arr_scale_values[z][0]
                arr_scale_values_z_1 = arr_scale_values[z][1]
                arr_scale_values_z_2 = arr_scale_values[z][2]
                diff_03 = cropped_image_ij_0 - arr_scale_values_z_0
                diff_04 = cropped_image_ij_1 - arr_scale_values_z_1
                diff_05 = cropped_image_ij_2 - arr_scale_values_z_2
                if diff_03 < 0:
                  diff_03 = - diff_03
                if diff_04 < 0:
                  diff_04 = - diff_04
                if diff_05 < 0:
                  diff_05 = - diff_05
                score_pixel = diff_03 + diff_04 + diff_05 

                if score_pixel < score:
                  score = score_pixel
                  dx_list = z
              velocity_image[i_frame, j_frame] = arr_scale_values_velocity[idx_list]  # the velocity is still in cm/s
  return velocity_image
```

for this you have to create a `setup.py` file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules=[ Extension("fastloop",
              ["fastloop.pyx"],
              libraries=["m"],
              extra_compile_args = ["-ffast-math"])]

setup(
  name = "fastloop",
  cmdclass = {"build_ext": build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules)
```

and then run the following from the command line:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Finally I imported the function in the main script

```
velocity_image = np.array(fastloop.extract_velocity(cropped_image, velocity_image, arr_scale_values, arr_scale_values_velocity, score))
```

I could get a speed up of more than 500x!!

Answer (score 0):

This nested for loop algo is already out of date. You can use fft, numpy already implement this method for you, or even fftfast.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).